# Trigger, at line 1 ORA 04098

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi im setting up some triggers and i cant get past this error

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger2
  BEFORE INSERT ON new_donation
  FOR EACH ROW
  --WHEN (new.contamt <= 10)
DECLARE

v_idno          VARCHAR2(5);
v_driveno       VARCHAR2(3);
v_contdate      DATE;
v_contamt       NUMBER(6,2);

BEGIN
 SELECT IDNO, DRIVENO, CONTDATE, CONTAMT INTO v_idno, v_driveno, v_contdate, v_contamt
 FROM OLD_DONATION2
 WHERE IDNO = :new.idno;
 IF :new.contamt < 50 THEN
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001, 'CONTRIBUTION TOO LOW FOR ' 
        || :new.idno || ' ' || :new.contamt);
   END IF;

END;
/
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
```

another part

```
DECLARE
  v_idno        new_donation.idno%TYPE := '&in_idno';
  v_driveno     new_donation.driveno%TYPE := '&in_driveno';
  v_contdate    new_donation.contdate%TYPE := '&in_contdate';
  v_contamt     new_donation.contamt%TYPE := &in_contamt;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO new_donation
    VALUES (v_idno, v_driveno, v_contdate, v_contamt);

END;
/
```

Im getting this error when I insert values at trigger2.

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-04098: trigger 'XXXXXXXXX.NEW_DONATION' is
>   invalid and failed re-validation ORA-06512: at line 7

All im trying to do is insert some values input by the user to this new table, which is empty.
Also  when donation amount is < 10 I want a error out.

Comment: Can you show `new_donation` structure ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps.

Run this query `select status from all_objects where object_name = 'TBL_USER_TRIGGER' and object_type = 'TRIGGER';`

If the status is invalid run `alter trigger trigger2 compile;`

Then run `show errors`

It will throw the errors for you. You need to fix those.